# How to gradually resize an image while scrolling the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wonder how I can **gradually** resize an image while scrolling up/down the page.

Please take a look at this example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8anvra8j/)

```
.image {
  opacity: .7;
}
```

I want the red heart to get smaller when scrolling down from the top of the page and bigger when scrolling upward. I'm gonna use this technique to have some fun with parallax on my website

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're already setting the `transform` CSS property for the image, just add `width` and/or `height` to the CSS being set. Also, what does that piece of CSS have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use transform:scale() instead of transform:translate(). The transform:scale() property used to resize object based on Scale (i.e:translate(2,2) mean resize to double size in both x,y axis). Here, Take a look for my little, not soo smooth example:

```
.image {
  opacity: .7;
  position:fixed;
}
```

i changed image position to fixed, so you can look it when it scroling:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var Scrolling = $(this).scrollTop();
   $('.image').css({
     'transform' : 'scale('+1/(Scrolling/30)+','+ 1/(Scrolling/30)+')'

   });
});
```

and, here is it the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8anvra8j/3/) link:   https://jsfiddle.net/8anvra8j/3/

- I hope this help.

Comment: Thank you a lot @DikaDikz. That works in resizing the image. But I really want it to get smaller as well as moving it down the page. So I put transform:translate() to the script. Can I do so at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var Scrolling = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('.image').css({
    'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ Scrolling/3 +'%)'
  });
});
```

```css
.image {
  opacity: .7;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}

img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="image">
  <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/C/m/R/8/C/K/small-red-heart-with-transparent-background.svg">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, viverra cras, magna porta sem at aenean sodales id, porta molestiae nibh nunc nulla mattis. Tellus turpis a ligula vestibulum lacus, quis massa sed. Gravida nulla aenean amet et, sed in ac enim lacus vel turpis, aenean ac platea, amet aenean ac pede rutrum mauris accumsan. Gravida elementum, pede adipiscing rutrum commodo, morbi vestibulum adipiscing nulla curabitur at amet, curabitur ac phasellus sed. Non in wisi morbi, libero quis arcu sit montes elit, augue euismod at, orci nullam nibh non. A magnis et eu, non felis hendrerit nec ipsum adipiscing hendrerit, morbi volutpat massa blandit a varius. Curabitur vitae est. Eget praesent sed est mauris felis, sed neque suspendisse non dictum.
    <br></br>
Commodo platea, congue curabitur placerat consectetuer placerat per pede, tellus nunc phasellus velit sociis repellat congue. Id sit mollis erat, mauris quam, ipsum tellus ut sit mauris arcu ac. Purus venenatis rutrum orci euismod duis a, semper libero pede tristique ultrices ac, pretium sociis orci posuere rhoncus et at, mi leo, leo per magna nec rutrum wisi. Sed penatibus sed scelerisque elit leo, purus dolor pharetra aliquam. Id egestas ipsum. A interdum vehicula, eget vitae eu libero donec a, vivamus venenatis fermentum. Accumsan suspendisse nam vel et eros varius, purus mauris, vel duis aptent ligula in velit, nec lacus urna pulvinar nunc vestibulum. Wisi vel neque ullamcorper adipiscing, tellus vitae eros tortor distinctio, nec non ut eleifend lectus donec et, nullam dui sed, imperdiet nam aliquam sodales. Ut at nibh molestie quis velit. Ac sit turpis, tellus ultricies semper, donec sagittis tellus venenatis, ac lacus montes. Nulla malesuada potenti natoque hac, aenean consequat at magna habitasse urna, suscipit nonummy mauris metus aliquam, diam id suspendisse.
<br></br>
Dui et quis eleifend lorem faucibus ac, a fusce dui semper arcu, nonummy magna et adipiscing tristique, maecenas non. Ut commodo sit sem nibh enim, dolor eget vel justo mauris lacinia lacinia, id erat aenean laoreet, vitae gravida convallis posuere mattis rutrum. A lacus odio, molestie nulla vehicula, risus neque ac augue nulla fusce feugiat, nascetur lacus, tincidunt faucibus wisi lorem velit justo sollicitudin. Tempor potenti mollis. Amet eu ut dictum posuere cupidatat in, vitae placerat mi quis justo, cursus vitae montes, sit eget eget non tempor, torquent arcu nec nibh. Ut per pellentesque, wisi tempus varius nulla malesuada. Ut nisl vitae vitae wisi sed, massa accumsan sem diam eros ante vitae, ullamcorper dui magna justo vestibulum vel praesent, eget morbi, sed vel vestibulum fringilla imperdiet. Nunc iaculis nulla in pellentesque dolor. Nibh vel ac nibh, vel aenean non vestibulum habitasse justo, velit placerat debitis condimentum sodales. Nunc eget quam mauris tellus et adipiscing, duis dictumst malesuada dignissim, eget vivamus tortor. Augue vitae.
<br></br>
Adipiscing orci, quam vel praesent per blandit elementum ut, sodales ornare tempora odio pretium lacus mattis. Rem eget laudantium ut quisque, integer dictum eu nonummy ipsum commodo, accumsan elementum iaculis vulputate fugiat, nec augue bibendum mattis. Blandit magna blanditiis sagittis risus ante integer. Eget et sed, placerat eget sollicitudin mauris amet proin, egestas scelerisque rhoncus orci. Aliquam dolor volutpat non eu turpis. Ornare tortor. Sed vestibulum amet porttitor platea, felis ut dapibus id, cursus ut velit pede cum amet consequat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, viverra cras, magna porta sem at aenean sodales id, porta molestiae nibh nunc nulla mattis. Tellus turpis a ligula vestibulum lacus, quis massa sed. Gravida nulla aenean amet et, sed in ac enim lacus vel turpis, aenean ac platea, amet aenean ac pede rutrum mauris accumsan. Gravida elementum, pede adipiscing rutrum commodo, morbi vestibulum adipiscing nulla curabitur at amet, curabitur ac phasellus sed. Non in wisi morbi, libero quis arcu sit montes elit, augue euismod at, orci nullam nibh non. A magnis et eu, non felis hendrerit nec ipsum adipiscing hendrerit, morbi volutpat massa blandit a varius. Curabitur vitae est. Eget praesent sed est mauris felis, sed neque suspendisse non dictum.
<br></br>
Commodo platea, congue curabitur placerat consectetuer placerat per pede, tellus nunc phasellus velit sociis repellat congue. Id sit mollis erat, mauris quam, ipsum tellus ut sit mauris arcu ac. Purus venenatis rutrum orci euismod duis a, semper libero pede tristique ultrices ac, pretium sociis orci posuere rhoncus et at, mi leo, leo per magna nec rutrum wisi. Sed penatibus sed scelerisque elit leo, purus dolor pharetra aliquam. Id egestas ipsum. A interdum vehicula, eget vitae eu libero donec a, vivamus venenatis fermentum. Accumsan suspendisse nam vel et eros varius, purus mauris, vel duis aptent ligula in velit, nec lacus urna pulvinar nunc vestibulum. Wisi vel neque ullamcorper adipiscing, tellus vitae eros tortor distinctio, nec non ut eleifend lectus donec et, nullam dui sed, imperdiet nam aliquam sodales. Ut at nibh molestie quis velit. Ac sit turpis, tellus ultricies semper, donec sagittis tellus venenatis, ac lacus montes. Nulla malesuada potenti natoque hac, aenean consequat at magna habitasse urna, suscipit nonummy mauris metus aliquam, diam id suspendisse.
<br></br>
Dui et quis eleifend lorem faucibus ac, a fusce dui semper arcu, nonummy magna et adipiscing tristique, maecenas non. Ut commodo sit sem nibh enim, dolor eget vel justo mauris lacinia lacinia, id erat aenean laoreet, vitae gravida convallis posuere mattis rutrum. A lacus odio, molestie nulla vehicula, risus neque ac augue nulla fusce feugiat, nascetur lacus, tincidunt faucibus wisi lorem velit justo sollicitudin. Tempor potenti mollis. Amet eu ut dictum posuere cupidatat in, vitae placerat mi quis justo, cursus vitae montes, sit eget eget non tempor, torquent arcu nec nibh. Ut per pellentesque, wisi tempus varius nulla malesuada. Ut nisl vitae vitae wisi sed, massa accumsan sem diam eros ante vitae, ullamcorper dui magna justo vestibulum vel praesent, eget morbi, sed vel vestibulum fringilla imperdiet. Nunc iaculis nulla in pellentesque dolor. Nibh vel ac nibh, vel aenean non vestibulum habitasse justo, velit placerat debitis condimentum sodales. Nunc eget quam mauris tellus et adipiscing, duis dictumst malesuada dignissim, eget vivamus tortor. Augue vitae.
<br></br>
Adipiscing orci, quam vel praesent per blandit elementum ut, sodales ornare tempora odio pretium lacus mattis. Rem eget laudantium ut quisque, integer dictum eu nonummy ipsum commodo, accumsan elementum iaculis vulputate fugiat, nec augue bibendum mattis. Blandit magna blanditiis sagittis risus ante integer. Eget et sed, placerat eget sollicitudin mauris amet proin, egestas scelerisque rhoncus orci. Aliquam dolor volutpat non eu turpis. Ornare tortor. Sed vestibulum amet porttitor platea, felis ut dapibus id, cursus ut velit pede cum amet consequat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, viverra cras, magna porta sem at aenean sodales id, porta molestiae nibh nunc nulla mattis. Tellus turpis a ligula vestibulum lacus, quis massa sed. Gravida nulla aenean amet et, sed in ac enim lacus vel turpis, aenean ac platea, amet aenean ac pede rutrum mauris accumsan. Gravida elementum, pede adipiscing rutrum commodo, morbi vestibulum adipiscing nulla curabitur at amet, curabitur ac phasellus sed. Non in wisi morbi, libero quis arcu sit montes elit, augue euismod at, orci nullam nibh non. A magnis et eu, non felis hendrerit nec ipsum adipiscing hendrerit, morbi volutpat massa blandit a varius. Curabitur vitae est. Eget praesent sed est mauris felis, sed neque suspendisse non dictum.
<br></br>
Commodo platea, congue curabitur placerat consectetuer placerat per pede, tellus nunc phasellus velit sociis repellat congue. Id sit mollis erat, mauris quam, ipsum tellus ut sit mauris arcu ac. Purus venenatis rutrum orci euismod duis a, semper libero pede tristique ultrices ac, pretium sociis orci posuere rhoncus et at, mi leo, leo per magna nec rutrum wisi. Sed penatibus sed scelerisque elit leo, purus dolor pharetra aliquam. Id egestas ipsum. A interdum vehicula, eget vitae eu libero donec a, vivamus venenatis fermentum. Accumsan suspendisse nam vel et eros varius, purus mauris, vel duis aptent ligula in velit, nec lacus urna pulvinar nunc vestibulum. Wisi vel neque ullamcorper adipiscing, tellus vitae eros tortor distinctio, nec non ut eleifend lectus donec et, nullam dui sed, imperdiet nam aliquam sodales. Ut at nibh molestie quis velit. Ac sit turpis, tellus ultricies semper, donec sagittis tellus venenatis, ac lacus montes. Nulla malesuada potenti natoque hac, aenean consequat at magna habitasse urna, suscipit nonummy mauris metus aliquam, diam id suspendisse.
<br></br>
Dui et quis eleifend lorem faucibus ac, a fusce dui semper arcu, nonummy magna et adipiscing tristique, maecenas non. Ut commodo sit sem nibh enim, dolor eget vel justo mauris lacinia lacinia, id erat aenean laoreet, vitae gravida convallis posuere mattis rutrum. A lacus odio, molestie nulla vehicula, risus neque ac augue nulla fusce feugiat, nascetur lacus, tincidunt faucibus wisi lorem velit justo sollicitudin. Tempor potenti mollis. Amet eu ut dictum posuere cupidatat in, vitae placerat mi quis justo, cursus vitae montes, sit eget eget non tempor, torquent arcu nec nibh. Ut per pellentesque, wisi tempus varius nulla malesuada. Ut nisl vitae vitae wisi sed, massa accumsan sem diam eros ante vitae, ullamcorper dui magna justo vestibulum vel praesent, eget morbi, sed vel vestibulum fringilla imperdiet. Nunc iaculis nulla in pellentesque dolor. Nibh vel ac nibh, vel aenean non vestibulum habitasse justo, velit placerat debitis condimentum sodales. Nunc eget quam mauris tellus et adipiscing, duis dictumst malesuada dignissim, eget vivamus tortor. Augue vitae.
<br></br>
Adipiscing orci, quam vel praesent per blandit elementum ut, sodales ornare tempora odio pretium lacus mattis. Rem eget laudantium ut quisque, integer dictum eu nonummy ipsum commodo, accumsan elementum iaculis vulputate fugiat, nec augue bibendum mattis. Blandit magna blanditiis sagittis risus ante integer. Eget et sed, placerat eget sollicitudin mauris amet proin, egestas scelerisque rhoncus orci. Aliquam dolor volutpat non eu turpis. Ornare tortor. Sed vestibulum amet porttitor platea, felis ut dapibus id, cursus ut velit pede cum amet consequat.
  </p>
</div>

</body>
```